# Collapse columns on mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database that manages items, tasks and passages of these items through doors.

Here is my tables:

Tasks table
[image: Tasks table]

Door passages table

[image: Door passages table]

Items per pass table

[image: Items per pass table]

Item history table

[image: Item history table]

I want to show a track record of everything that happened to an item. Something like this:

[image: Track record]

In short, I have a task history table and a passages history table, I want to display it to the user as a single table (general history of some item).

Note that some columns were collapsed. How to do this query?

Comment: You want "task details" results following "task" results? Not how SQL was designed to be used. Might be possible, but would require an extremely cumbersome, unintelligible, and ugly query.

Comment: This will be possible with multiple `UNION ALL`, but you'll need to be careful with making each result return the same columns in the same order.  For example, when you pull from the door passage table, `direction` needs to be mapped to `name`, `details` and `date_creation` need to be nulled, etc...

Comment: Thanks Llama. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I made a UNION between the task table and passages table. Both selects should have the same number of fields. When a column in a table does not exist in the other, I put null. When a column should be concatenated with another one, I put the same name for both